# Embedding a never-ending Wordpress blog in an iframe?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wordpress, iframe, embed

I'm trying to embed a wordpress blog into a page on our website. The actual blog doesn't display 10 posts per page though; it keeps growing when you scroll down, aka. never-ending.

I've tried setting the height to huge amounts, or setting it to auto, but all to no avail. Any ideas?

```
<iframe src="http://myblog.wordpress.com/" width="100%" height="50000" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a late answer but someone might find it useful.

I've done the same thing for an existing project. It consisted of the following

1. Wordpress' `XML-RPC API`s
2. `XML-RPC.NET` Library
3. `Ajax` actionlink to load more posts
4. Caching

**Wordpress' XML-RPC APIs**

Have a look at Wordpress' `XML-RPC API`s, these allow you to communicate directly with your Wordpress installation. There is a whole list of methods you can use such as getting all posts, adding posts, etc and its quite easy to add your own by modifying some `PHP` files.

You can find the documentation [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API)

**XML-RPC.NET Library**

You might have came across `XML-RPC` if you have done php in the past but its generally not common for `.NET` developers. So to make life easier I ended up using Charles Cook's `XML-RPC.NET` library. This handy library creates the remote calls and even deserializes the response.

Heres my code to get posts

```
public interface IWordPress : IXmlRpcProxy 
{

    [XmlRpcMethod("wp.getPosts")]
    Post[] GetPosts(int blog_id, string username, string password, PostFilter filter);

}


public class PostFilter
{
    //Ignore the first...
    public string offset { get; set; }
    //Bring back this many posts
    public int number { get; set;
}


public struct Post
{
    public string post_id { get; set; }
    public string post_title { get; set; }
    public string post_status { get; set; }
    public DateTime post_date { get; set; }
    public string post_content { get; set; }
    public string post_author { get; set; }

}
```

Ensure that the property names match those outlined in the Wordpress API documentation otherwise they will not map.

You can find XML-RPC.NET [here](http://xml-rpc.net/)

**Ajax actionlink to load more posts**

Like you I wanted to load posts dynamically so I ended up using the [Ajax Actionlink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.actionlink%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) to create async requests to my controller, which in turn called the Wordpress APIs.

Here's my code

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Load more posts!", "action", "controller", 
    new { offset = Model.Offset },                  
    new AjaxOptions
    {
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter, 
        UpdateTargetId = "post-items",
        OnSuccess = "loadItemsSucccess",
        OnBegin = "loadItemsBegin"
    }, null)
```

As you can see I am passing over the offset value which we pass over to the wp.getposts method. It tells the wordpress api to ignore the first x amount. You just need to keep changing this value as posts come in.

**Caching**

Generally it was quite quick at loading 9 posts at a time, including images, but you should consider doing some form of caching. I ended up just using the standard [output cache attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx).

Whilst my solution doesn't use an iframe, I think it gives a bit more flexibility since you have direct control over your data.

Hope this helps.